# Slick create a new session and keep it open

Tags: oracle, scala, session, akka, slick

My scala application works with Oracle Database which has the limit of active sessions. 
I'm using AKKA actors for concurrent tasks with Oracle DB by Typesafe Slick.

This is the example of work for actors:

```
def marketPlaceDataRefresh[T](targetArea:String, customerId:String, wave:String) =    
  clientPool.withClient(targetArea.toUpperCase) {
    implicit session =>
      sql"""BEGIN MARKETPLACE_PKG.INIT_DATA_REFRESH($customerId,$wave,$wave,$wave); COMMIT; END;""".as[Int].firstOption
  }
```

Implicit session opening and closing every time when def marketPlaceDataRefresh called by AKKA actors.

I know only the basics of concurrency and Slick.

How can I create a single session and keep it open for all concurrent tasks?

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question, just a consideration, I don't think you should do that, sessions are opened, used and then returned to the db session pool, it's a fast and safe mechanism, what would happen if you had a session open in an actor and maybe is not used? Or even worst if the actor crashes and the session is not correctly closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session should not be kept opened for a long time. That being said, you can always handle session manually. From [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/connection.html#manual-session-handling), you can open a session using:

```
val session : Session = db.createSession
...run the queries normally...
session.close // close the session
```

However, I will never use something as risky as that. Sooner or later, there will be a bug and the session will escape(i.e. you will forget to close it) bringing your db to halt.